# Retrieve maximum value for the last 10 records in objective c

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I want to retrieve the `maximum value` of last 10 records in `sqlite` database, I use the below query but it retrieve the `maximum value` for all the `column` not for only the last 10, how I can solve this problem?

```
select ifnull(Max(Systolic),0)  from PressureAndHR order by ID desc limit 10;
```

Thank u,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to modify from

```
select ifnull(Max(Systolic),0) from PressureAndHR order by ID desc limit 10;
```

to

```
SELECT ifnull(Max(Systolic),0) FROM (SELECT * PressureAndHR ORDER by ID DESC limit 10);
```